# Make USB keyboard wireless

Tags: usb, keyboard, bluetooth, wireless-keyboard, wired

I use a keyboard that is not available in a wireless or bluetooth version, but connects to the computer via USB. Is there any way to make this keyboard wireless? In other words, is there something small I can plug the keyboard wire into that will broadcast the signal wirelessly to be picked up by something plugged directly into the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with something like [this](http://www.everythingusb.com/cables-unlimited-wireless-usb-adapter-kit-15823.html). If I get it correctly, it comes with power injector. Still, you'd need to connect the injector to power and that means wires.

I can't find any battery powered injectors at the moment, but you could always make one yourself. Still, it's going to be complicated and it's going to be a hack.

Unfortunately, as far as I can see, there's no elegant solution to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this project https://github.com/Terminus-IMRC/usb2bt/ could provide a solution. It is a USB to Bluetooth software bridge based on Arduino hardware.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1209360)